# python2.7 accessing object (oop related)

Tags: python, oop, object

I'm new to python. Inside my main.py I defined this code to start a local FTP server using this [library](https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib).

```
authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("user", "12345", "/home", perm="elradfmw")
handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
server = FTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 21), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Then I create a new folder named modules with a class called GameServer. Inside this class gameserver I defined a method (static) to deleteFTPAccess(username). How to call this method now using the FTP server defined inside the main.py?

My structur of files:

```
main.py
   modules
     gameserver.py
```

gameserver.py

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

class GameServer ():

    def __init__(self, id, ip_address, port):
        self.id             = id
        self.ip_address     = ip_address
        self.port           = port

    @staticmethod
    def deleteServer(id):
        #delete FTP access
        authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
        authorizer.remove_user(id)
```

main.py

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
from modules.gameserver import GameServer

authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("user", "12345", "/home", perm="elradfmw")
handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
server = FTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 21), handler)
server.serve_forever()

GameServer.deleteServer("user")
```

When deleting a server it doesn't effect the FTP, meaning I can access the server using the username after deleting. From my point of view, the usage is wrong.

Comment: `GameServer.deleteServer("user")`

Comment: `handler = FTPHandler` doesn't make an instance of `FTPHandler`. That looks wrong.

Comment: Fixed code above, I think the problem is located somewhere else. Updated error above.